# Determine what's being initialized in Instruments App Launch Initializer Calls

Tags: xcode, instruments, static-initialization

I'm trying to determine what actions to do to improve the performance of our app. I'm using the App Launch template of Instruments in Xcode. I see a bunch of large blocks of time spent on static initializer calls, There's an address in hex but I don't know how to use that to find where is this static initialization taking place:

[image: Static Initializer Calls]

Our app is rather large and has a bunch of dependencies, so I'd like to know if it's possible to know what's being initialized so I can move it elsewhere without manually looking for static initializers and randomly moving stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by double clicking on the Running Block of the Main Thread, Like this:
[image]